# Simulating clicks with Java for webDriver

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem. In my test I need make a clicks on some areas of activity. This areas doesn't have any locators, that's why I make a design do a coordinate click.

For this moment I have this code:

driver.getMouse().click();

But I don't know what argument (what type of argument) I should use for correct working of this approach.

How to make a coordinate click using WebDriver?

Please, help me

Comment: How to make a coordinate click using WebDriver?

Answer (score 1):

It is answered here: [How it is possible click on specific coordinates with selenium2 webdriver in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5347613/675065)

See http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions

It is still work in progress and only available in the HTMLUnit Driver at the moment. I don't know when the port for C# will be ready.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like that:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.click(myElemment);
action.perform();
```

If you want to make it in one line you also could make the same doing this:

```
new Actions(driver).click(myElemment).perform();
```

Where driver is the WebDriver object and myElement is the WebElement you can get using driver.findElement(By. ...)