# Click element with selenium2library

Tags: webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

My whole test suite is based on robotframework with the SeleniumLibrary (RC). I'm trying to port it to Selenium2 (webdriver). I'm facing an issue with the **Click Element** keyword which does not support **coordinates** argument anymore. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347613/how-it-is-possible-click-on-specific-coordinates-with-selenium2-webdriver-in-c) which mentions a MoveToOffsetAction but cannot find it whithin the Selenium2Library seen from robotframework.
I also read that the webdriver API has a *click_at(locator, coordString)*

To sum up the situation, I'm wondering how to convert my selenium RC *Click Element Locator Coordinates* to a Selenium2 keyword or set of keywords.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Pierre

Answer (score 2):

In Selenium2 API there is no option to click the element using the co-ordinates.

But you can resolve the issue by using the `Action` class.

**Try this code:**

```
 //Assume driver is instantiated somewhere properly.
 WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Element locator));       
 Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
 builder.moveToElement(ele, 100, 200).click().perform();
```

By using the above code you can move to the particular element using co-ordinates(here button) and able to click.

For more info http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I'm trying to write a new keyword `Click Element On Coordinates` to be able to replace my old `Click Element` statements. The problem is that I don't know how to get the current webdriver instance that may have been created when first importing the Selenium2Library into Robotframework test suite...

Comment: If the above solution resolves your problem mean make it as answer.